# ggplot: Reorder Facet rows in facet.grid

Tags: ggplot2, facet

I am having issues reorganizing my rows using facet.grid. I have four groups that by default are organized alphabetically. Using the factor command I can organize the groups - but they switch to columns (horizontal) and I need rows (vertical).

Example of subset of my data

```
Site            Date       Analyte    Result
   SJR@Calaveres    5/26/22    Top TP    0.35     
   SJR@Ship Channel 5/26/22    Top TP   0.56
   Turning Basin    5/26/22    Top TP    0.46
   Morelli Boat Ramp 5/26/22    Top TP  0.45
   Public Dock      5/26/22    Top TP     0.55

wi_daily_wq<-read.csv("nutrients_p.csv")
 p <- ggplot(data = wi_daily_wq, aes(x = Date, y = Result))+
   geom_point(aes(color = Site)) +
   theme_bw()
 p
 
 # Add vertical facets, aka divide the plot up vertically since they share an x axis
 p + facet_grid(Analyte ~ .)
 
 # Add vertical facets, but scale only the y axes freely
 p + facet_grid(Analyte ~ ., scales = "free_y")
 p + facet_grid(Analyte ~ ., scales = "free_y",
                switch = "y") # flip the facet labels along the y axis from the right side to the left


#Trying to organize rows in order that I want  
p + facet_grid(~factor (Analyte,levels=c('Bottom TP','Top TP','Bottom PO4','Top PO4')))
         ylab(NULL) + # remove the word "values"
       theme(strip.background = element_blank(), # remove the background
             strip.placement = "outside")  # put labels to the left of the axis text
```

[image]
If I remove the following argument from the above code I get the row plot I like. But, the rows are just in alphabetical order, not the order I need them in.

```
p + facet_grid(~factor (Analyte,levels=c('Bottom TP','Top TP','Bottom PO4','Top PO4')))
```

I'm wondering what adjustment I need to make to my code to organize the rows in the order I need them without converting the facets to columns.
[image]

Comment: Try with `facet_grid(factor(Analyte,levels=c('Bottom TP','Top TP','Bottom PO4','Top PO4'))~.)`- You switched rows and cols compared to your first codes.

Comment: Thank you! I knew, I was putting ~. in the wrong place but couldnt figure out where it went. The only issue now is that when I add the new code it overwrites scales = "free_y", switch = "y" Is there a solution to have both ordering and the free_y and switch = y incorporated?